# Simple framework MVC: how to associate the controller actions to urls?

Tags: php, frameworks

I have followed [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/create-your-first-tiny-mvc-boilerplate-with-php/) nice video tutorial to create a mini MVC PHP framework.

As you can see, the guy creates an action called `home()` inside the Controller class to show the main page.

Now, I need to create another action called `foobar()` that shows another page, but how can i associated it to an url in a simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually done by routing. If the first part of the URL identifies the controller and the second the action, you extract those variables and route accordingly.

A very basic example:

```
$action = 'foobar';
$controllerName = 'whatever';

if(class_exists($controllerName)){

    $controller = new $controllerName;

    if(method_exists($controller, $action)){

        $controller->$action();

    }
}
```

Obviously, `$action` and `$controllerName` are obtained from the URL.

This code snippet tries to call the method 'foobar' inside a class named 'whatever'.